# Not able to find MSCVR90.dll

Tags: visual-c++

Mine is activex plugin which generates .ocx file. when i opened with dependency walker it shows it depends on MFC90.dll and MSCVR90.dll. it is there in amd64_mfc and amd64_crt folder.

MFC90.dll depends on MSVCR90.dll and it shows it is not found even though it is there in amd64_crt folder.

Meanwhile i installed VC++ redis package it has mfc90.dll and mscvr90.dll in VC/redist foler.

Should i want to use this files for linking or what?

Comment: Replacing Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable with its [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) probably resolves the issue. (Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3412380/908336)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 64 bit version of dependency walker? It sounds like you app is compiled for 32 bit, and so you need the 32 bit visual studio c/c++ runtimes installed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have a [manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332473/msvcr90-dll-dependency-in-vs-2005-c-project/332545#332545) issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled with 64bit version. I am using 64bit version of dependency walker.

for your reference i have given below the manifest file as well.